# NodeJs : Passport Bearer + Api (google, fb, ...)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, bearer-token

I'm developping a restful api with NodeJs and PassportJs for authentication. 
To avoid sessions, (stateless), I use bearer token (passport-http-bearer) to authenticate users (client side : AngularJs).

However, I have an issue when I want to link facebook account with google one.
Create different accounts is easy but linking them to one user, I don't know how to proceed (I think that a way is to propagate the token across the remote API).

Here is my code for passport strategies :

```
passport.use('bearer-login', new BearerStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true },
    function(req, token, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            jwt.verify(token, parameters.secret, function(err, decodedToken){
                if(err) return done(err);
                User.findOne({
                    _id: decodedToken.userid,
                    usernameCanonical: decodedToken.username
                }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    if (!user) return done(null, false);
                    return done(null, user, {
                        scope: 'all'
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    }
));

passport.use('github-login', new GithubStrategy({
    clientID: parameters.github.clientId,
    clientSecret: parameters.github.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: parameters.github.callback,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'github.id': profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        if(err) return done(err);
        if(!user){
            var user = new User({'github.id':profile.id, 'github.token':accessToken, 'github.name': profile.name});
            user.save(function(err){
                if(err) return done(err);
                return done(null, user);
            })
        } else {
            if(!user.github.token) {
                user.github.token = accessToken;
                user.save(function(err){
                    if(err) return done(err);
                    return done(null, user);
                })
            } else return done(null, user);
        } 
    });
  }
));
```

And here my auth routes:

```
router.route('/auth/github/login').get(passport.authenticate('github-login', {session: false}));

router.route('/auth/github/callback')
    .get(passport.authenticate('github-login', { session: false, failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:8080/login' }), 
        function(req, res, next){

            var token = jwt.sign({
                userid: req.user._id,
                username: req.user.usernameCanonical
            }, parameters.secret);

            res.writeHead(302, {
            'Location': 'http://localhost:8080/categories?token=' + token
            });
            return res.end();

        });



router.route('/auth/current')
    .get(passport.authenticate('bearer-login', {session: false}), function(req, res){
        return res.send({username: req.user.username});
    });
```

Do you have an idea how to proceed ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is impossible without at least some form of session cookie. When you open up a new browser window for OAuth, there is no way to control the headers so bearer won't work.

I'm working on the best way to tackle this and will answer here if I figure it out.

Comment: Thanks! Using state to send bearer token is not a good solution ?

Comment: I got it working using '?access_token={token}' in the URL for /facebook and /facebook/callback pages. I had to look at the source of passport-http-bearer to figure it out. It works without cookies. I will post an answer with full source code in the next few days.